# StickyListHeader not grouping headers properly

Tags: android

I've implemented [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) but it's not working quite as I intend it to. The headers does not seem to group properly. See the image below, which pictures each (collapsed) header.

Header 2 and 4 are, as you can see, same. They have the same Id, but is not grouped as they should.

[image: example]

Below is my adapter code. (View-related code removed for readability)

```
public class PartyMemberArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PartyMember> implements View.OnClickListener, StickyListHeadersAdapter {

    private ArrayList<PartyMember> members;

    public PartyMemberArrayAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<PartyMember> members) {
        super(c, R.layout.list_item_party_member, members);
        this.members = members;
    }

    @Override
    public View getHeaderView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        HeaderViewHolder holder;
        View row;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            holder = new HeaderViewHolder();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header_party_member, viewGroup, false);
            holder.party = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_list_header_party);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            row = view;
            holder = (HeaderViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.party.setText(PartyUtil.getFullPartyNameFromAbbr(members.get(i).getParty()));
        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public long getHeaderId(int i) {
        //There's 8 different parties, each with 8 names with unique length as I use for ID.
        return PartyUtil.getFullPartyNameFromAbbr(members.get(i).getParty()).length();
    }

    private class HeaderViewHolder{
        TextView party;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return members.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PartyMember getItem(int position) {
        return members.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here? Is it not enough that I return a unique ID for the headers to group properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by implementing a sort algorithm, which sorted the underlying data set based on which header they "belonged" to.

```
    Collections.sort(members, new Comparator<PartyMember>() {
        public int compare(PartyMember p1, PartyMember p2) {
            return p1.getParty().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getParty());
        }
    });
```